# Dynamically (?) creating TextViews and display XML content

Tags: android, dynamic, textview

I am working on an android application and I've run into some difficulties. Let me first explain a bit.
The application works on extracting information from a local xml file and then displaying that information in the TextView.

Now my question is, how can I display the info from each xml block in its own TextView, so the user will be able to to manipulate with one of the displayed xml blocks (ex. changing color, font size etc.) and not affect the others. There is no fixed number of the blocks in the xml file.

I suppose I would have to create TextViews dynamically for each of the xml blocks?

I don't even know where to start... no actual code is needed, just adice on how to deal with this. I can give further explanations if needed.

[Xml file](http://www.gcc.si/projectblue/fizika/elektrika.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Create a linearlayout in xml but put nothing in it. Give it an id.

In code:

```
LinearLayout layout = findviewbyid(R.layout.mylinlayout);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("stuff");
tv.setWhateverpropetiesyouneed

layout.addView(tv);
```

You can add as many text views as you want. Try set+getTag() for finding the view later for user manipulation. Or just deal with it in whatever listener you have.

Comment: The problem is that the code has to create a TextView when it is needed, and there is no finite number of TextViews that would be required.